# Error: Page "/api/auth/[...nextauth]" is missing "generateStaticParams()" so it cannot be used with "output: export" config

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I am working on Next.js project in which I have implemented user authentication using
next-auth and Google Provider. When I am trying to create the build for the project the the complier throws this error "Error: Page "/api/auth/[...nextauth]" is missing "generateStaticParams()" so it cannot be used with "output: export" config."
This is my api > auth > [...nextauth] > route.js file

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google"

export const authoptions = {
    providers : [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId : process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret : process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET
        })
    ],
    secret : process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
    callbacks : {
        async redirect(){
            return process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL;
        }
    }
}

const handler = NextAuth(authoptions)

export {handler as GET, handler as POST}
```

This is my code for api > auth > [...nextauth] > route.js file

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    output : "export"
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

This my code for next.config.js file

Comment: do you have any dynamic route in your project?

Comment: @Yilmaz yes I have a dynamic route.

Comment: does not this `output : "export"` mean you are building a static app

Comment: yes, I read the docs and realized that I was creating the build wrong way. @Yilmaz Can you help in creating the build. I am not building a static app

Comment: just run `npm run build`??

Comment: okay I'll try that

Comment: export is for static website. every page must be static `npm run build` for production building

Answer (score 1):

If you are not building a static site then remove  output : "export" from the nextConfig file. The authentication process is dynamic thus can not be rendered as static.